# Material TabLayout Access Issue

Tags: android, material-components-android

I am using support design version 28.0.0 in my app and trying to use material tablayout in XML.

**com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout**

unfortunatly i am unable to access it in XML. Any help is appreciated.

I have used 
**android.support.design.widget.TabLayout**
but now i want to use material tablayout as per new documentation

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout

Answer (score 3):

You have to include the Material Components library in your app `build.gradle` file:

- If you're using androidx:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

- If you're not:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha3'
```

More information is available here: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md